# Save WebResponse as txt

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking for a method equivalent to Request.SaveAs in WebResponse. But I can't find it.

I want to store in txt file the headers and the body of a webresponse.

Do you know any technique to achieve it?

Comment: what are you trying to do, log all responses from your ASP.NET app ?

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, I will connect by WebRequest and use the GetResponse method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no builtin way, but you can simply use the [GetResponseStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.getresponsestream.aspx) method to get the responce stream and save it to a file.

---

**Example:**

```
WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com");
using (WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    // use whatever method you want to save the data to the file...
    File.AppendAllText(filePath, myResponse.Headers.ToString());
    File.AppendAllText(filePath, reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

---

Nonetheless, you can wrap it into an extension method

```
WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com");
using (WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse())
{
    myResponse.SaveAs(...)
}
```

...

```
public static class WebResponseExtensions
{
    public static void SaveAs(this WebResponse response, string filePath)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            File.AppendAllText(filePath, myResponse.Headers.ToString());
            File.AppendAllText(filePath, reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is a good way to do it. Why annidate the usings? Should be best run one using and later the second?

Comment: I think using StringBuilder you gain clearity and only writes one time to disk: `code`             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(response.Headers.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine();
            sb.Append(responseTxt);
            File.AppendAllText(filePath, sb.ToString()); `code`

Comment: Note, this will buffer all the request in memory. You wouldn't be able to download files >512Mb on 32bit OS. And in this case you would "download it to swap first"

Comment: There's a bigger problem with encoding too.

Answer (score 1):

WebClient class have ResponseHeaders collection :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.responseheaders.aspx

Comment: So you suggest make manually this task. Is not any Method or tecnique... Am I wrong?

Comment: yes, I am not aware of something that will do this automatically, why don't you use WebRequest and WebResponse ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not using Webclient, I'm using WebRequest and WebResponse.