# Open a WebResponse on Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, webresponse

I have a Request which I make to a page and works fine. I can also view that page the response page with Fiddler.

But how do I open this response in my browser?

Currently what I have:

```
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie("test","this");
            cookie.Domain = "foobar";


            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create("http://foobar/ReportServer/");
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            request.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream sr = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader sre = new StreamReader(sr);
            string s = sre.ReadToEnd();
            Response.Write(s);
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "open this response in my browser".

Comment: @CodeCaster For instance there is Response.Redirect(URI). I want to do this same functionality but i already have my request and response and would just wish to open up this response in the browser. Right now what I'm doing which works is doing a request which saves info related to the user on the other site foobar then I redirect them like Response.Redirect(url), creating what seems like to me a redundant thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

[Save it to an HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347751/save-webresponse-as-txt) and [open the browser with the path to that file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580263/how-to-open-in-default-browser-in-c-sharp).

Comment: I like this idea. But the Response is from another asp.net page. I don't think html will behave properly. Since usually when you attempt to save a .aspx page in html it doesn't work

Comment: It's very unclear what you want this code to do then. When does this code run? Why doesn't `Response.Write(s);` do what you want it to?

Comment: When I do Response.Write(s) which I thought would be the solution it does nothing. Even when I look at fiddler, nothing. The code runs off a button click on a web page on domain 'foo'  the request is to page 'foobar'.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have addressibility to the request "Stream" you can use this method: NavigateToStream :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostream(v=vs.100).aspx

```
  this.webBrowser.NavigateToStream(sr);
```

Comment: I'm using a web application

Answer (score -1):

You can use System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control.